# Trimming new line characters via BASH

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a file that is structured as a number of sections separated by a specific text `foo`. I'd like to join all lines within a region, but leave the separators in place. In short, I want it this way :

input text file :

```
bar 
bar
bar bar  
foo
bar  
bar bar bar
```

output text file :

```
bar bar bar bar   
foo  
bar bar bar bar
```

That is, a newline character is permissible only when the next line is `foo`

Kindly help me with an awk/sed/perl script for the same.

Comment: This isn't very easy to understand. Would it be fair to say that you want to join together all lines, except for specific separator lines?

Comment: Please check my rewrite to see if it matches your intent. Hopefully, you'll be able to get a few more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '/^foo$/ { if (NR>1) printf("\n"); print; next } { printf("%s ", $0) }'
```

Comment: Can be simplified by doing `awk '!/foo/{printf("%s ", $0);next}{print "\n"$0}'`

Comment: @Jaypal You should post that as an answer. Also put an `END { printf("\n") }` to ensure the file ends with a newline.

Comment: I can't Michael, it has been inspired by your solution. If you are ok then you can add it as an alternate solution to your answer. I have been following your answers and blog (applied abstraction) since last few months and they have helped me learn `awk` a lot. :)